# Handling multiple page-level binding providers

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here's my scenario.

I would like to create a separate KnockoutJS binding provider for handling translations on my pages that will read a `data-alias` attribute for any element either present on page load or created after page load (possibly created in a sub-template that's rendered by knockout) and retrieve translations for the alias and apply them as the text of the element. I would still like to be able to independently call `ko.applyBindings(model, element);` to process the page's `data-bind` attributes but I would like to have a separate call to `ko.applyBindings` so that the translations can get applied for the `data-alias` attribute. Anyone know how I can support both and have them behave independently?

Here's an example of how the process should go.

The HTML markup/template:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend data-alias="SomeTitle"></legend>
    <div class="row-container">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" data-alias="LabelAlias"></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: SomeObservable" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" data-alias="AnotherLabelAlias"></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: AnotherObservable" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

On page load, there would be a call to apply bindings with the binding provider for data-alias:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // Lets assume translations is a dictionary of alias to translation
        // that is loaded with the page synchronously
        ko.applyBindings(translations); 
    });
</script>
```

Also on page load, there would be a service call to retrieve the data needed for the page and upon retrieval it would apply bindings to the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({...}) // Omitted for brevity
            .done(function(data) {
                var viewModel = new my.namespace.SomeViewModel(data);
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            });
    });
</script>
```

The intended effect:

- The page loads.
- The translations are applied.
- A service call is kicked off to retrieve the data.
- The service call returns.
- The data is converted into a view model and bound to the page (and the translations are retained).

Comment: You can only have one binding provider active at one time for the current instance of KO.  One thought would be to create a binding provider that wraps the real binding provider, but exposes a "mode" to determine what to look for.  Then, you could set this mode when doing your translations binding.

Comment: Yeah, that might work. I'll look into it when I get a chance.

Comment: So your first page-load call gets the translation bindings, then the second call takes the result of those bindings to get the translation?

Comment: The second call is independent of the first call. I just want the first call to be synchronous with the page and the second to be asynchronous.

Comment: could you not merge these into one viewmodel? and when applying the translations, simply initialise `viewModel` (call `my.namespace.SomeViewModel`) with some empty data. then populate this empty section with your ajax call. no need to call `ko.applyBindings` more than once

Comment: Hmm... that might work actually. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use knockout for the data that comes back from the service call.

But don't use knockout for the translations - what you want to do there can be handled without a framework like knockout.  Here is how you can do it:

```
var translations = {};
translations["LabelAlias"] = "Bonjour";
translations["AnotherLabelAlias"] = "Au Revoir";

$("[data-alias]").each(function(index, element){
    var aliasName = element.getAttribute("data-alias");
    var aliasValue = translations[aliasName];
    $(element).text(aliasValue);
});    ​
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qjGwR/

**Update**
You mentioned you had dynamically loaded content that you want to translate.  Not a problem!  I've updated the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qjGwR/1/.

```
function translate(translations, selector) {
  if (selector == null) { selector = ''; }
  $(selector + " [data-alias]").each(function(index, element){
    var aliasName = element.getAttribute("data-alias");
    var aliasValue = translations[aliasName];
    $(element).text(aliasValue);
  });
}

translate(helloTranslations);

// Add something to the DOM
var moreContent = '<label class="control-label" data-alias="ThirdLabelAlias">Three</label><div class="controls"><input type="text" data-bind="value: somethingElse" /></div>'

$('#moreContent').html(moreContent);
translate(helloTranslations, '#moreContent');​
```

We move the translation act to a method, pass in the translations that we want to apply, and tell it what part of the DOM we want to translate.

Comment: Yeah, I had originally thought of going that route. The only problem with that route, however, is that not all of the DOM elements of the page are created when the page loads. We're using nested, recursively defined templates that can also be modified after the page loads by the user. So while that route will work for the initial page load, any DOM elements created on the page AFTER it is loaded, will not get localized.

Comment: See update for how to take care of content that is dynamically loaded.